# External Service too fast for database in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, web-services, eloquent

I have an application which is connected to an external webservice. The webservice sends messages with an ID to the laravel application. Within the controller I check if the ID of the message already exists in the database. If not, I store the message with the ID, if it exists I skip the message.

Unfortunately sometimes the webservice sends a message with the same ID multiple times within the same second. Its an external service, so I have no control over it.

The problem now is, that the messages come so fast, that the database has not saved the message before the next message comes into the controller. As a result, the check if the ID already exists fails and it tries to save the same message once more. This leads to an exception, because I have a unique identifier on the ID column.

What is the best strategy to handle this? To use a queue for it, is not a good solution, because the messages are time critical and the queue is even slower and it would lead to a message jam/congestion within the queue.

Any idea or help is appreciated a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can send to your database `INSERT IGNORE` requests

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO messages (...) VALUES (...)
```

or

```
INSERT INTO messages (...) VALUES (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating on duplicate. That is a way I have used in the past to get around issues like this. Not sure if it's the perfect solution, but definitely an option. I assume you are using mysql.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html